# Processing standard output for logs (process backspace and delete characters in a string)

Tags: c#, string, replace, command-line-interface, control-characters

When running a console application and redirecting the output to my own stream, I receive all the control characters used to create text based progress-bars and percentages etc...
Writing this to a file and opening it in an editor shows these characters as small boxes.

Is there any standard routine or function I can call to process a string with these characters (so for example: when a backspace is encountered, the backspace and the previous character are both removed).

I've rolled my own with only backspace support which works for now, but I'd like to have it generic so that the next command-line app that uses cursor movement and Delete characters, Home, End etc... will also output a proper logfile (as seen on screen).

The routine should not have any UI requirements (I could send each character to a textbox control, but I'm running on a server).

Does anyone know of such a generic C# string processing lib? (probably I'm missing the correct keyword)

Comment: *Don't* log them. All  logging frameworks allow you to specify multiple targets and filters. *Progress* bars though simply don't need to be logged

Comment: If by "logging" you mean "redirect standard output to a file" again, don't. Use a proper logging framework, especially if you want to display user-only messages in the console. Or create Powershell commands instead of console applications. Powershell has separate channels for error, progress, debug, information messages etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm writing a very generic piece of code that will run any executable in a certain directory, and I really have to log the output. Comparable to Build automation, but in other ways quite different.

Comment: Would you take screenshots of a UI App for logging? Because that's basically what you are doing.

Comment: @Fildor, yes, that's kind of the idea, with a "deferred UI" :-) Yeah, I could process the chars when displaying the "log", but why sore the chunky thing when not needed.

Comment: Do you have control over those "executables in a folder"s' code?

Comment: @LouisSomers then create powershell commands. You don't need to write any more code and you do get standard pipelinse and channels. *Build automation* tools use proper logging too, they don't depend on standard output. Unit testing tools export result reports in XML. Build tools themselves show minimal info to the console and log detailed info to files

Comment: @LousSomers the OS and platform already provide facilities for what you want anyway. Don't try to reinvent them

Comment: @Fildor No, these are mainly 3rd party executables. Our own code is run directly from calling an interface in DLL's and is allot more sophisticated. But there's really a need for generic command-line support in addition so non-programmers (operations / admins) can do allot more without any required code changes.

Comment: @LouisSomers btw Powershell provides workflows and runbooks to run multi-step scripts. Operators/admins *know* how to work with Powershell. If you want to work with them, use their tools and stack

Comment: In that case I couldn't agree more with Panagiotis.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly, that's why I'm asking this question, I just can't find any c# lib that'll do the magic. It's quite trivial to write myself, but why reinvent what already exists (if it does).

Comment: @LouisSomers I already mentioned PowerShell 3 or 4 times.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, I'll look into hosting powershell as a more elegant solution, but I don't consider it as an answer to the question. I'd still like to keep "logs" of the screen output of these 3rd-party apps.

Comment: One workaround is to view the logs in the console using the type command, eg `type StdOut.log`... works, but not very elegant.